# Adding "301 Redirect" to a large number of files in IIS 6

Tags: iis-6, redirect, files

I am trying to create a permanent (301) redirect all the files in a directory to a single file within that directory.

For instance, if a user visits site.com/directory/randompage.html, I want them to be redirected to site.com/directory/index.html.

I have tried putting a redirect on the directory and then overriding the redirect on the file level, but IIS does not appear to allow this.

Is there a way to accomplish what I am after? or do I have to create a redirect on a file by file basis?

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For attempted access to files that don't exist you can put a custom 404 error on the directory that redirects the user to the URL for the file you'd like them to access.

If there *are* other files in that directory you'll have to put redirects on them on a file-for-file basis. That's just the way it is, unfortunately. If you have a lot of files you could script the metabase modification to add the redirect.

Edit:

If you can modify the NTFS ACLs on all those files to disallow the user from reading them, you could also drop a custom 401.3 error page on the directory, too.

If not, then try this:

```
@echo off
SET SOURCE_DIR=C:\path-to-directory-in-filesystem
SET ADSUTIL=cscript C:\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs
SET METABASE_PATH=W3SVC/####/ROOT/path/to/site/directory
SET REDIRECT_URL=/foo/foo.txt

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`dir /b %SOURCE_DIR%`) do (
 %ADSUTIL% CREATE %METABASE_PATH%/%%i
 %ADSUTIL% SET %METABASE_PATH%/%%i/KeyType "IIsWebFile"
 %ADSUTIL% SET %METABASE_PATH%/%%i/HttpRedirect "%REDIRECT_URL%, PERMANENT"
)
```

Set the SOURCE_DIR to the physical path in the filesystem of the directory with the files to be made into redirects. ADSUTIL is probably set right if you're a stock IIS 6 install. METABASE_PATH needs to refer to the site identifier number (### in the sample, get it from the IIS management console for your site) and the path under the root (leave /ROOT/ there-- that needed). Finally, REDIRECT_URL needs to be the URL (can be absolute or relative to the root of the site).

Comment: Thanks!  There are a few thousand files unfortunately.  Can you direct me to a decent resource for scripting the metabase modifications?

Comment: There-- have at.  >smile<

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to employ a URL rewrite module to do this.  There are 2 that I know of for IIS6 and earlier, IIS7 has it's own module (finally).

You can have a look at Helicon's [**ISAPI_Rewrite**](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) or [**Ionics Isapi Rewrite**](http://www.codeplex.com/IIRF) (also works with IIS7).  I use Ionics' because it's free, but Helicon's rewrite rules I believe map directly with the mod_rewrite Apache module's rules which is a big win for it in general.

Both have the ability to provide permanent redirects and the rules are regular expression based.  I'll see if I can put together the syntax for a rule that would cover what you want to do and post it shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (just to have it out there), is you could tell IIS to let ASP.Net handle .html in that site, then create a global.asax file with Application_BeginRequest code that checks the URL and redirects accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

All that metabase modification- thousands of files you say? You could do this with one wildcard rule in [IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com).

```
RedirectRule ^/directoryToRedirect/(.*)(?<!index\.html)$  /index.html  [L]
```

In english, it says, for any URL in the directory *directoryToRewrite*, which is NOT index.html, redirect it to index.html .

This works regardless of how many files you have, whether you add new files, remove files, whatever.